# Moving Charge and Magnetic Field

Tags: electromagnetism

A moving charge produces a magnetic field. But what are the conditions of this motion? Does the motion have to be translational or can it be rotational ? In other words, can a rotating point charge, that is fixed, produce a magnetic field? Why or Why not?

Comment: Any accelerating charge will produce an electric and magnetic field which one can see by maxwell's equations.

Comment: In both cases of Rotational and translational motion?

Comment: There must be producing a change in the electromagnetic fields, if a charge with spherical symmetry is rotation on itself, they'll be no change because of the symmetry and thus no magnetic field.

Comment: @RishabhJain To produce a magnetic field, a charge need not accelerate. A uniform velocity will also produce a magnetic field.

Comment: @AnmolVashishtha There are no conditions on the motion of a charge to produce a magnetic field. Any sort of motion will produce a magnetic field. However, when it accelerates, it gives off electromagnetic radiation.

Answer (score 1):

*Quick Pedantic Digression*

In ***Classical Electrodynamics***, the limit of a point charge, in other words the limit of of a sphere of charge of density $\rho \propto {1 \over R^3}$ where $ R$ is the radius of the sphere is not a well defined limit  (one way to see this is that the electrostatic energy stored in the field would blow up as $\lim_{R->0}{q^2 \over R}$).  So one has to be careful when discussing the "point charge" limit.

*Back to Question*

In general, moving charge densities described by some current density $\vec{J}(\vec{r},t)$, and density $\rho(\vec{r}, t)$ produce both electric and magnetic fields of the form described by the Lienard Wiechert Potentials.  These are pretty ugly expressions of the fields, but there's no conceptual problem in calculating the fields.

Now if you consider a model of a sphere of charge of density $\rho$, radius $R$, spinning about its axis at $\omega$, this also produces a magnetic field, which looks like a magnetic dipole field on the outside of the sphere.  This is a famous calculation, which you can do using the Biot Savart's law (this context is slightly more constrained than the general lienard wiechart case because it concerns magnetostatics, not electrodynamics).

In the limit as $R \rightarrow 0$ and $\rho \rightarrow \infty$, the magnetic dipole vanishes, so the magnetic field goes to 0.